# How can I add another input layer to a multiple input model using functional api?

Tags: keras

I have already a model that has multiple input layers. Now I want to add layers before one of these input layers. What should I do?

```py
# this is my current model, it has two inputs m1_in and aux_in
model = Model(inputs=[m1_in, aux_in], outputs=[m2_out])

# build some new layers
x = Input(shape=(32,))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

# now I want feed the result of the output layer to the input layer m1_in
```

My problem is I can't use functional API here, like `new_output = model(output)` because `model` has multiple inputs. I cannot specify which input layer I want to connect.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add layers before one of these input layers"? It's functional API wherever you initialized `Input()` that will behave as input layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a model for the new layers, define new inputs, and then define a new combined model. Make sure to not lose the input for the original layers (the `x`).

```
# Model for new layers
comb_model = Model(x, output)

# New inputs
new_m1_in = Input(...)
new_aux_in = Input(...)

# Apply new model for new layers
comb_m1 = comb_model(new_m1_in)

# Apply old model with new model input
final_out = model(comb_m1, new_aux_in)

# Build final model
final_model = Model([new_m1_in, new_aux_in], final_out)
```

Hope it works. This is the beauty of the Functional API :)

Comment: Thanks! it worked! In the step ```final_out = model(comb_m1, new_aux_in)``` I used ```final_out = model([comb_m1, new_aux_in])```. Thank you again! you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

First you should call all your layers `x` but revelant names as `dense_1`
I don't undersatnd what you want but maybe things like this

```
# this is my current model

# build some new layers
in_ = Input(shape=(32,))
dense_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(in_)
dense_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_1)
dense_3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_2)
dense_4 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(dense_3)

model = Model(inputs=[m1_in, aux_in, in_], outputs=[dense_4])
```

Or last line

```
model = Model(inputs=[in_], outputs=[dense_4])
```

But you should be more specific ?

Comment: sry, my problem is: ```model1 = Model(inputs=[m1_in, aux_in], outputs=[m2_out])``` it has multiple inputs. And now I load a new model like ```model2 = load_model()```, and I want to feed the result of ```output = model2(input)``` to ```m1_in```, which is one of the inputs of ```model1```, but I cannot use functional API here, because functional API can't specify which input to feed.